# Excel VBA - access controls on a Mac

Tags: excel, vba, forms, controls

How do I find out the names of Form Controls such that I can access them in VBA? VBA and forms in Excel on OS X seem to have changed dramatically in the last couple of years and seems far more constrained than previously.

Specifically, I'm trying to update a spinner button's min and max properties.

**Edit**

I've used the following to identify the object:

```
For Each obj In ActiveSheet.Shapes()
    Debug.Print (obj.OLEFormat.Object.Name)
Next
```

and then

```
Set mySpinner as Shape
Set mySpinner = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Spinner 26")
```

But I'm at a loss as to why Excel VBA offers a SpinButton type if it can't be used!?

Many thanks,

Mat